# PyCharm file scheme

Tags: pycharm

My modified (under git) files in PyCharm CE appear in this all but unreadable foreground color.

[image: unreadable filename]

I'm using a (copied and renamed) Monokai scheme. I'd like to stick to a dark UI background.

I gathered that fixing the foreground color of these modified files ought to be adjusted from Preferences\ Editor\ Colors&Fonts\ File Status\ Modified. But this one, along with several other guesses, are not the one.

Can you guess where the right entry lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences\ Editor\ Colors&Fonts\ File Status\ Modified

is indeed the right entry, but it doesn't propagate after Apply/OK. One must close the filelist and reopen it.